# How to send Typeface from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I'm working on a "Logo Maker" project.... now i'
m facing a problem with sending Typeface from one activity to another

This is what i have tried:

***AddTextActivity:***

```
tt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            var="font1.ttf";
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(AddTextActivity.this.getAssets(), "font1.ttf");

            edtText.setTypeface(tf);

        }
    });

 Intent intent=new Intent();

            intent.putExtra("color",fontColor);  
            intent.putExtra("msg",message);     
            intent.putExtra("style",var);       

            setResult(2,intent);
            finish();
```

***LogoEditorActivity:***

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==2)
    {
        String color=data.getStringExtra("color");  //this works fine
        String message=data.getStringExtra("msg");  //this works fine also
        String style=data.getStringExtra("style");

        Log.e("style",style);


                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(LogoEditorActivity.this.getAssets(),style);
                sticker = new TextSticker(this);

                sticker.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.sticker_transparent_background));
                sticker.setText(message);
                sticker.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
                sticker.setTextAlign(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
                sticker.resizeText();
                sticker.setTypeface(tf);          //this not working
                stickerView.addSticker(sticker);

    }
}
```

> Simply how to set Font TypeFace to a sticker.setTypeface()....

Comment: Log.e("style",style) what this line prints?, also post code of TextSticker.

Comment: i'm using StickerView....
https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView

Comment: sticker is an object of TextSticker...

Comment: i have checked sticker.setTypeface(tf);   is working fine, where is your font located in project? it must be in /main/assets folder